# Vuforia jPCT integration and build jni

Tags: android, vuforia, jpct

I getting following error while running imagetarge vuforia jPCT project

```
 W/dalvikvm(3469): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c4e648)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(3469): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.qualcomm.ar.pl.CameraPreview.newFrameAvailable:(IIII[B)V
    E/AndroidRuntime(3469):     at com.qualcomm.ar.pl.CameraPreview.newFrameAvailable(Native Method)
   E/AndroidRuntime(3469):  at com.qualcomm.ar.pl.CameraPreview.onPreviewFrame(CameraPreview.java:805)
  E/AndroidRuntime(3469):   at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:791)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3469):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
E/AndroidRuntime(3469):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3469):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3469):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3469):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
 E/AndroidRuntime(3469):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I read all vuforia blog and google search but not able to solve problem

Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used latest vaforia.jar to solve problem

Download latest sdk from https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/android